# Sci-kit learn machine learning script for 2 datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

Not alot of wisdom here... But I have a script that will compile and test the algorithm two times with the `for i in range` loop to see if there is any variation in root mean squared error.

Is it possible to modify the code where the loop will work to test two different datasets? IE, a `df` would run first one time compile rmse and then a `df2` could run compile rmse and then I can compare/print the rmse between the two.. Both datasets would have the same `['Demand']` as the response variable.

```
#Test random Forest

import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, neighbors
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import math

rmses = []
for i in range(2):

    X = np.array(df2.drop(['Demand'],1))
    y = np.array(df2['Demand'])

    offset = int(X.shape[0] * 0.7)
    X_train, y_train = X[:offset], y[:offset]
    X_test, y_test = X[offset:], y[offset:]

    clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=60, min_samples_split=6)

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))
    rmse = math.sqrt(mse)
    print("rmse: %.4f" % rmse)
    rmses.append(rmse)

print(sum(rmses)/len(rmses))
```

Comment: do you mean train and test on one df and then repeat for df2? or train on df and test on df2?

Comment: Yes train & test one data. Then train & test another data set, compare results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an auxiliar df and assign the dataframe you want to compile on each iteration by using a condition:

```
for i in range(2):
    if i==1:
        aux_df = df
    else:
        aux_df = df2
    .
    .
    .
```

That way you can use the first `df` in the first iteration and `df2` in the second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of dfs and iterate over that:

```py
rmses = []
df_lst = [df1, df2]
for df in df_lst:

    X = np.array(df.drop(['Demand'],1))
    y = np.array(df['Demand'])

    offset = int(X.shape[0] * 0.7)
    X_train, y_train = X[:offset], y[:offset]
    X_test, y_test = X[offset:], y[offset:]

    clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=60, min_samples_split=6)

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))
    rmse = math.sqrt(mse)
    print("rmse: %.4f" % rmse)
    rmses.append(rmse)

print(sum(rmses)/len(rmses))
```

Comment: When I run this I get an error that list cannot `df.drop`

Comment: can you show the exact error? you probably have to define the axis when dropping